# Can I disable the trycompile step when generating project with cmake?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to generate some projects for Visual Studio 2015 with CMAKE on Windows 10. It appears that the trycompile step fails complaining that a target manifest file is missing. The file is actually there, but it seems there's something strange with msbuild that's causing this behavior.

Since I'm mostly interesting in generating the project and then building with Visual Studio I'm wondering if it's possible to disable the trycompile step and just leverage cmake's generation?

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not saying what is failing (CMake I suppose), and you should copy paste the actual error message.

Comment: You can't disable it., You might try deleting it from the CMake file ... BUT ... chances are good that the build will fail. The try/compile is there to ensure your system is compatible for the build. Unless the developer wrote stuff that is superfluous, whatever error it's detecting is probably important. Post it. The try/compile section might be useful too.

Comment: This can be very helpful in cases where CMake has a bug... in XCode iOS SDK detection, for example...